# Flutter: _TypeError

Tags: flutter, dart, http, flutter-future

I'm trying to get datas from api and add them a list. But at this moment, I see datas i got but I can't get it out of the function. What should i do?

**function**

```
  List<dynamic> xxx = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Future<List<dynamic>> fetchCompanies(List<dynamic> datas) async {
      var response = await Dio().get(CompaniesPath().url);
      if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
        Map<String, dynamic> company = jsonDecode(response.data);
        for (int i = 0; i < company['Data'].length; i++) {
          datas.add(company['Data'][i]);
        }
        //print(datas); //=> I see datas here

      } else {
        throw Exception();
      }
      return datas;
    }

    print(fetchCompanies(xxx));
  }
```

When I run `print(fetchCompanies(xxx));` I got `"Instance of 'Future<List<dynamic>>'".` How can i get data inside `fetchCompanies` to my `xxx` list?

Comment: can you provide your JSON data?

Comment: My problem has solved. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to print future instance of List that's why you got

> Instance of Future<List>

**You have to wait until function finish executing.**

Catch here is you can't call wait in  `initState()` so you have to use `.then` method

try this:

```
fetchCompanies(xxx) 
.then((result) {
    print("result: $result");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It should already work fine like it is. But you probably want to call a `setState` to refresh the page. Try this:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Future<List<dynamic>> fetchCompanies(List<dynamic> datas) async {
      var response = await Dio().get(CompaniesPath().url);
      if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
        Map<String, dynamic> company = jsonDecode(response.data);
        for (int i = 0; i < company['Data'].length; i++) {
          datas.add(company['Data'][i]);
        }
        //print(datas); //=> I see datas here

        setState(() {}); // added this

      } else {
        throw Exception();
      }
      return datas;
    }

    print(fetchCompanies(xxx));
  }
```

Comment: Other solution has solved my problem, my page got datas but this time didn't refresh it. And i used your solution(setstate). So, both of your answers helped me a lot. Thank you so much